# Release managment list of available build templates is empty

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management, tfs-2013

I am configuring a new Release path using Release management 2013 Update2 for TFS2013.  I configured the connection to TFS Collection under Administration tab, but when I go to Release's properties and try to select the appropriate Build definition both drop downs Team project and build definition are empty.

RM is running a service account that is part of Admin collection and the RM service is also using that same account.

Comment: Seems to be a common issue, either reinstall or change to http rather than https. Search on here there are 3 or 4 similar questions

Comment: to change to HTTP do I have to modify some RM config file? because in RM --> Administration --> Manage TFS my connection is already set to HTTP

Comment: Sounds as though your already set. As I said I had to reinstall, https was from another answer. Have a search

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved by simply enabling only Windows authentication on RM IIS.